# Update exif-date out of filename

Tags: linux, exif

I have a rather big amount of files named like

```
S2_20170228_161143.png
```

with no useful exifdata in it

How could I write/update exif-data (date/time pic taken and the first segment (S2 in this case) as keyword) ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ is probably where you should be asking, but what you are looking for is a script written around exiftool.

Comment: Are they definitely PNG files? What app are you expecting to take notice of EXIF data in a PNG  file - have you tested that?

Comment: its a web-gallery that deals with the data

Comment: So does this command set the date such that your web-gallery correctly finds & understands it? `exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal=2000:01:02 12:30:45" someFile.png`